# Loop inside a loop performance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The only reason I'm posting this is because I actually believe that my code perfomance is being affected by this code block where I use a foreach loop inside another one.

I was wondering if anyone would suggest anything different that could help the performance or perhaps point out some other flaws in the code.

```
    public override void DisplayScore()
    {
        byte MessageLocation = 0;
        foreach (var kvp in PlayerScores.OrderByDescending((s => s.Value)))
        {
            if (MessageLocation == 5)
                break;

            if (MessageLocation == PlayerScores.Count)
                break;

            foreach (var player in PlayerList.Values)
            {
                SendMessage(MessageLocation, "My text");
            }
            Score++;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it's just displaying the top 5 scores (in different locations) from a dictionary in a descending order and sending them to a list of players from another dictionary.

Comment: what is the content of send message? is this an email?

Comment: what is `MessageLocation` and where you are updating its value?

Comment: Your code looks bad, but it definitely does not generate any performance problems. Such simple constructions like `foreach`, `break` etc. will not cause performance problems until you have millions of records. Try to profile it, or at least try to debug it. Most probably, the problem is somewhere in `SendMessage`.

Comment: Process it in parallel, with for example Parallel.ForEach (easiest method). This way it will be as fast as you will get it for 2 simple loops i guess.

Comment: Who many members your PlayerScores collection have? Because sorting can cause performance issue.

Comment: How many members your PlayerScores collection have? Because sorting can cause performance issue.

Comment: We can't really tell what's wrong without knowing how long things are taking, how large your collections are, or what `SendMessage` does. Please post a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't understand this code. What is the relationship between `PlayerScores` and `PlayerList` It looks like me that you're looping first on the `PlayerScores` collection and *for each* score, you send a message to *each* player. Meaning you will send a message to each player multiple times. If we don't consider performance at the moment, **does this code do the right thing?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the double loop is the problem. I suggest to check the LINQ query `PlayerScores.OrderByDescending((s => s.Value))`. Depending on the numbers of scores this might take its time to order, espesially if the values come from a dictionary. The internal structure of a dictinary makes it expensive to enumerate through keys and values.

You can test it with the following code (slightly improved) and [Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn973013.aspx), where it can be seen, how long single execution steps take:

```
public override void DisplayScore()
{

    var scores = PlayerScores.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value).Take(5).ToArray();

    foreach (var kvp in scores)
    {
        foreach (var player in PlayerList.Values)
        {
            SendMessage(MessageLocation, "My text");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's actually expensive to iterate over all the entries in a dictionary - it's just that it's not as quick as looking up by keys. Also note that the assignment to `scores` in your code will be very quick due to the lazy nature of LINQ queries - it's not actually doing any of the sorting at that point. If you wanted to *actually* split the LINQ part from the rest, you'd need to materialize the query.

Comment: Yes your right with the lazyness of LINQ. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested for loops you may gain some performance by adding the scores to a list and then sending them to the players eg:

```
//List containing player and score

foreach (var kvp in PlayerScores.OrderByDescending((s => s.Value)))
{
         //Add scores to list       
}

foreach (var player in PlayerList.Values)
{
         //Send scores to players
}
```